# Why tilde goes to new line, if it is followed by Enter key?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

When you press tilde (`~`, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>), it does not appear. You have to press any other key to see it.

If you press that *any* key, it always goes *after* tilde. So, for example, if you press tilde and then `@` symbol (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>) you'll end up with `~@`.

There's one, single exception. If you follow tilde with <kbd>Enter</kbd> you'll end up with tilde in a new line. Which means, that in this case, enter / new-line character was inserted *before* tilde. Why?

Comment: You don't indicate what operating system or software you're using.  However, international characters that look like letters with punctuation marks above them are often entered by typing the accent character followed by the letter.  Tilde is one of these.  After typing the tilde, the computer waits to see what character you enter next to know whether to treat it as a tilde or a special character.  That's likely why the behavior in the first part of your question.  Don't know if tilde+enter is just a weird artifact of that or your software might have a bug.

Comment: Try `~` followed by `n` to see if you get ñ

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 with Polish keyboard, so `~` + `n` gives me `ń`, not `ñ`, but I to get the idea. Thanks.